# Linear Algebra base and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Is to find base space and dimension columns or rows, I must rate matrix canonical or rate a normal way?

thank's

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the basis of the column space of $A$, one needs to find the set of vectors $\beta$ such that $\text{span}(\beta) = \text{col}(A)$ and the vectors are linearly independent.